# Why MySQL workbench is making all my foreign keys unique?

Tags: foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I've created a MySQL Model with a few tables, some of them with fk's to another table. I usually export the SQL from MySQL Model to my database using the "Forward Engineer SQL CREATE Script" inside File -> Export -> Forward Engineer SQL CREATE Script. The problem here is that when I generate the creation script, all my fk's become unique. I didn't check UQ option in MySQL Model but it creates a script with unique fk's anyway, so, I need to change the SQL file generated and remove all the unwanted uniques. Anyone has a clue why this is happening?[image: Table description]

Generated script:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `u514786799_detranleiloes`.`Lotes` (
  `createdAt` DATE NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` DATE NOT NULL,
  `id` INT UNIQUE NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `LeiloesId` INT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  `conservado` TINYINT NULL,
  `numero` INT NOT NULL,
  `CRDsId` INT UNIQUE NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_Lotes_Leiloes_idx` (`LeiloesId` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Lotes_CRDs1_idx` (`CRDsId` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Lotes_Leiloes`
    FOREIGN KEY (`LeiloesId`)
    REFERENCES `u514786799_detranleiloes`.`Leiloes` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Lotes_CRDs1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CRDsId`)
    REFERENCES `u514786799_detranleiloes`.`CRDs` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Comment: did you specify the cardinality of the reference, maybe mysql thinks its a 1:1

Comment: I used a 1:n non-identifying relationship